# Differential equation Minimum Norm Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> y'(t) = −α y(t)+ x(t) ; y(0) = 0

We want to find an input x(t) that meets the constraint y(1) = 1 (0 ≤ t ≤ 1) (assuming α = 2 ).
I want to find x(t) - the minumum norm solution.
Someone please help. And no it is not my assignment.

Comment: If someone can refer me to some literature that can help me solve this. please i need it urgently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a non-homogeneous differential equation, which I'll write as

$$\dot{y}+\alpha y=f(t)$$

Solve the homogeneous equation first, i.e., $f(t)=0$ to get a particular solution, and this should give you an idea of what to put in for $x(t)$ provided your boundary values.

Comment: So i solved it for homogenous equation, but x(t) is of unknown shape, so how can i find particulat solution

Comment: You should have an exponential function for your particular solution. If you assume f(t) also has this form you can use something like the method of undetermined coefficients.